# Android - Broadcast Receiver works on Emulator Not on Phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have written a simple app which atm just pops up a toast message when the network state changes.  This works perfectly on the emulator but I've tried it on 2 different android phones and it seems like the broadcast reciever is never trigger on these events.
This is my broadcast reciever:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
  {       
      Toast.makeText( context, "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();     
  }
}
```

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
..
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
..
        <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
..
    </application>
<!-- Needed to check when the network connection changes -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

Anyone know why this is happening or what I might have done wrong?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: I'm surprised it works on the emulator - it shouldn't. Trying to interact with the UI in general from a non-UI component (such as a `BroadcastReceiver`) isn't how to do things. If this is for testing purposes only at this stage, then simply use a call to `Log` and connect the phone to your dev machine to watch logcat. Alternatively (for testing purposes) get your `BroadcastReceiver` to generate a status bar notification.

Comment: Thank for the reply.  I have tried System.out.println("sometext") as well which again outputs to logcat in emulator but not on devices

Comment: If you're testing this by toggling the Wi-Fi network then you may also need the `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` permission. Also you could try listening for `android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE`.

Comment: Testing by toggling Airplane mode..

Comment: Try using `Log.d("XYZ", "sometext")` - I may be wrong as I never use `System.out.println(...)` with Android but I don't know if will output to logcat on a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find anything obviously incorrect in your code, so here is a best-effort.

In your manifest place the  block AFTER the

PVS

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, tried that, still no luck.  I'm pretty sure the receiver isn't being triggered at all I just don't know why.  I've also tried putting the broadcastreciver inside the service which again works on the emulator but not on a device.